# Como verificar uma senha criptografada durante o Login?

Tags: php, segurança, hash

Quando eu tento logar:

- se eu uso o nome do usuário e senha errados, só aparece o conteúdo do `header` e do `footer`.
- se eu uso o nome do usuário e senha corretos, o login não reconhece o usuário:
  **"Wrong username and password combination"**.

  ```
  <?php
  $page = 'Login';
  session_start();
  include 'header.php';

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  header('location: control-painel.php'); 
  }
  else{

  $user_error = '';
  $pass_error = '';
  $login_error = '';

  if(isset($_POST['login'])){

  $username = $mysqli -> $_POST['username'];
  $password = $mysqli -> $_POST['password'];
  $cost = '11';
  $salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
  $password_hash = crypt($password, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');
  $id = 0; 

  if(empty($username)){
      $user_error = 'Please insert a username';
  }
  if(empty($password)){
      $pass_error = 'Please insert a password';
  }
  if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

      $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?');
      $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password_hash);
      $stmt -> execute();
      $stmt -> bind_result($id);
      $stmt -> fetch();

      if($id){
          $login_error = 'Wrong username and password combination';
      }
  }
  }
  if(empty($user_error)&& empty($pass_error)&& empty($login_error)&& isset($_POST['login'])){

  $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?');
  $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, $password_hash);
  $stmt -> execute();
  $stmt -> bind_result($id);
  $stmt -> fetch();

  if($id){        
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      header('location: control-painel.php');
  }
  }
  else{
  ?>

  <div class="message">
  <br><br>
  <?php echo $user_error; ?><br><br>
  <?php echo $pass_error; ?><br><br>
  <?php echo $login_error; ?><br><br>
  <br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="form" class="bradius">
  <div class="content">
      <form method="post">
          <label>Username: </label>
          <input type="text" name="username" class="text bradius">
          <label>Password: </label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="text bradius">
          <input type="submit" class="submitbutton bradius" name="login" value="Login">
      </form>
  </div>
  ```

  ```
  <?php
     }
  }
  include "footer.php";
  ?>
  ```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish/

Comment: Eu já vi ele antes mas não entendi a parte da verificação.

Comment: Você criptografa a senha digitada no *login* exatamente da mesma forma que fez no *signup* (no cadastramento) e faz uma comparação simples.

Comment: Recebe essa mensagem de onde? Nada do que você postou indica que isto deva acontecer. Poste algo mais que possa nos dar uma ideia melhor do que você fez.

Comment: Para testar, experimenta só pegar o valor do campo `password`, imprima ele e imprima o `$password_hash` para ter uma avaliação visual da diferença entre eles. Você tem certeza que está criando o `$password_hash` exatamente igual ao cadastro?

Comment: Você está usando uma variável chamada `$password_hash`, eu imaginei que ela tivesse sido *hashada* exatamente como no cadastro, como eu já falei antes. Se ela está guardando `senha321` você tem uma senha pura, e não um *hash* de uma senha. Aparentemente `$2a11$Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ$` é um *hash* de uma senha, então você tem que comparar com outro *hash* e não com uma senha pura.

Comment: Você editou a pergunta, mas inverteu o IF que eu pus na resposta. Além de estar com código duplicado desnecessariamente. O que eu coloquei na pergunta já é suficiente, basta pequenos ajustes nas variáveis só. Preste atenção no IF da resposta original. Logado está dentro do IF, e senha errada dentro do ELSE, e não no IF como você fez. E além disso você está misturando o escape string com o bind, portanto, vai ter problemas de validação.

Comment: @Lukaz11 fiz mais uns ajustes no código, lembre de atualizar aí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **IMPORTANTE** Esta resposta foi dada para a situação colocada na pergunta.
>
> **Não use** `crypt` e *salt* fixo para guardar senhas, e em PHP utilize a função `password_hash` e `password_verify` para senhas.

### Resposta original:

Faça o hash de novo na senha que o user digitou, e veja se bate com o do DB:

```php
// Pego a senha do POST (adapte pro seu código)
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Aqui estamos fazendo o mesmo que você usou para encriptar. Mas dá pra melhorar isso.
$cost = '11';
$salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
$password_hash = crypt($password, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');

// Agora comparamos o HASH da senha digitada com o HASH da senha salva
// porém, deste jeito, você está vulnerável a SQL Injection.
$mysqli->query(
   "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password_hash."'"
);
```

Veja como fica o código acima usando `bind_param`, para evitar *SQL Injection*:

```php
// Pego a senha do POST (adapte pro seu código)
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Inicializamos o id do usuário com 0 para usar no fetch()
$idUsuario = 0;

// Aqui estamos fazendo o mesmo que você usou para encriptar. Mas dá pra melhorar isso.
$cost = '11';
$salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
$password_hash = crypt($password, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');

// Agora comparamos o HASH da senha digitada com o HASH da senha salva:
$query = 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password_hash );
$stmt->execute();

// Aqui pegamos o resultado.
// se for mais de um campo, pode ser bind_result( $idusuario, $username, $email...
$stmt->bind_result( $idUsuario );
$stmt->fetch();

if ( $idUsuario ) {
   echo 'Logado';
} else {
   echo 'Usuario e/ou senha invalidos';
}
```

### Resposta atualizada com a edição da pergunta:

Segue refatoramento usando os princípios indicados:

```php
<?php
   $page = 'Login';
   session_start();
   include 'header.php';
   $user_error = '';
   $pass_error = '';

   if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header('location: control-painel.php'); 
   } else {

      if( isset($_POST['login'])) {
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $cost = '11';
         $salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
         $password_hash = crypt($password, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');
         $id = 0; 

         if(empty($username)){
            $user_error = 'Please insert a username';
         }
         if(empty($password)){
            $pass_error = 'Please insert a password';
         }

         if( empty( $user_error ) && empty( $pass_error ) ) {
            $mysqli = new mysqli//ABRIR SUA CONEXAO AQUI CASO NAO ESTEJA NO HEADER
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?' );
            $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $username, $password_hash );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $id );
            $stmt->fetch();

            if($id){
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               header('location: control-painel.php');
               die();
            } else {
               $user_error = 'User or Password invalid';
            }
         }
      }
   }
?>

<div class="message">
   <br><br>
   <?php echo $user_error; ?><br><br>
   <?php echo $pass_error; ?><br><br>
   <br><br>
</div>
<div id="form" class="bradius">
   <div class="content">
      <form method="post">
         <label>Username: </label>
         <input type="text" name="username" class="text bradius">
         <label>Password: </label>
         <input type="password" name="password" class="text bradius">
         <input type="submit" class="submitbutton bradius" name="login" value="Login">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>

<?php
   include "footer.php";
?>
```